# SystemStackError (stack level too deep) when a button is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whenever I include this erb 
`<%= button_to 'Update All', edit_multiple_matters_path, params: { contact_ids: @a } %>` if I go to a different paginated page or return a significant amount of records from filtering I encounter this error. This error also occurs if I simply submit blank filters. No errors are present if I remove the button.

Error (it highlights the above erb button).

```
SystemStackError in MattersController#index (stack level too deep)
app/views/matters/index.html.erb:59:in `block in _app_views_matters_index_html_erb___969156382226184390_70194338945860'
app/views/matters/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_matters_index_html_erb___969156382226184390_70194338945860'
```

Controller that it points to.

```
  def index
    @q = Matter.ransack(params[:q])
    @c = @q.result(distinct: false)
    @matters = @c.page(params[:page]).order(contact_id: :DESC)
    @a = @c.ids
```

I send the data to this simple method.

```
def edit_multiple
  @matters = Matter.find(params[:contact_ids])
end
```

The button actually works fine if I just return results and use it. If I remove the button everything works, searching, filtering, pagination, etc. Even my other button that does edit_multiple when things records are checked has no issues.

So for some reason this lone button is causing issues and I'm unsure why as I can't tell where recursion would occur.

Full view

```
<%= render 'layouts/filter' %>

<%= form_tag edit_multiple_matters_path, method: :post do %>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" id="select-all" /></th>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :contact_id, 'Contact ID', default_order: :desc) %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :account_name, 'Account Name') %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :phone_number, 'Phone Number') %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :retain_status, 'Retain Status') %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :sol, 'SOL') %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :referring_partner, 'Referring Partner') %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :settlement_name, 'Settlement Name') %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :modified_time, 'Modified Date') %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% if @matters.count > 0 %>
    <% @matters.limit(50).each do |matter| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag "contact_ids[]", matter.contact_id %></td>
      <td><%= link_to matter.contact_id.to_i, matter%></td>
      <% if matter.account_name.present? %>
      <td><%= matter.account_name %></td>
      <% else %>
      <td><%= matter.last_name.to_s + ', ' + matter.first_name.to_s %></td>
      <% end %>
      <% if matter.phone_number.present? %>
      <td><%= matter.phone_number %></td>
      <% else %>
      <td><%= matter.alternate_phone_number %></td>
      <% end %>
      <td><%= matter.retain_status %></td>
      <td><%= matter.sol %></td>
      <td><%= matter.referring_partner %></td>
      <% if defined?matter.settlement_name %>
      <td><%= matter.settlement_name %></td>
      <% else %>
      <td>NO DATA</td>
      <% end %>
      <td><%= matter.modified_time.to_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %></td>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
</table>

<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page-item">
    <%= paginate @matters %> <strong> <%= @matters.total_count %> </strong> Records </p>
  </li>
</ul>

<%= submit_tag 'Edit Checked', class: 'btn edit-btn' %>
<% if current_page?('/matters/', check_parameters: true) %>
<% else %>
<span class="float-right">Download: <a href="/matters.csv?<%= request.fullpath.split("?")[1]  %>">CSV</a></span>
<%= button_to 'Update All', edit_multiple_matters_path,  data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to update #{@matters.total_count} records?" }, class: 'btn btn-danger', params: { contact_ids: @a } %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Longer trace

```
actionview (5.1.5) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:637:in `block in to_form_params'
actionview (5.1.5) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:635:in `each'
actionview (5.1.5) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:635:in `to_form_params'
actionview (5.1.5) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:332:in `button_to'
app/views/matters/index.html.erb:59:in `block in _app_views_matters_index_html_erb__1889869573385807202_70354043510660'
actionview (5.1.5) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:39:in `block in capture'
actionview (5.1.5) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:203:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (5.1.5) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:39:in `capture'
actionview (5.1.5) lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:70:in `form_tag'
app/views/matters/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_matters_index_html_erb__1889869573385807202_70354043510660'
actionview (5.1.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
```

Comment: Show the whole view, might be the error is somewhere close.

Comment: I've added the full view. Let me know if there is anything else to clarify. I feel like it should be a simple fix and adjusting the erb for the button might do the trick.

Comment: Yes, it _looks_ like a simple fix, but so far nothing stands out. :/

Comment: Post more of a stacktrace, maybe?

Comment: Added the longer trace. It actually breaks if I just load something with ?page=2 appended to the URL. For some reason the button really hates pagination. Have had 0 issues with pagination with anything else including a similar button.

Comment: What is `@c.ids`? Not a simple array, I assume?

Comment: `@c.ids` is a simple array of integers that looks like this [142141, 122131, 123123, ...].

Comment: __Is__ it a simple array of integers or it only __looks__ like one? (not familiar with ransack api). What is `@c.ids.class`?

Comment: `@c.ids.class` returns `Array`.

Comment: Odd. My edit checked button that works just fine gets ruined by having his button present. It almost overrides it. Ignores what's checked after being filtered and returns all values.

Comment: Yah, I'm out of ideas. This needs some debugging. :)

Comment: Trying! :) Looking at the html it creates tons of name="contact_ids[]" value="123123" and my guess is when it loads the page it has a hard time rendering so many. Is there a way around this?

Comment: how many is that?

Comment: "Is there a way around this?" - pass fewer ids into the button_to :)